# Is there a good method for finding an orthogonal basis for $L^2(S^2)$ given some measure preserving $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems

I'm interested in studying the hyperbolic dynamics of the sphere and I have a list of properties that I want a function $f : S^2 \to R$ to satisfy given a specific measure preserving $T : S^2 \to S^2$.  It would really simplify things if I can find a "good" orthonormal basis for the unitary operator $U_T(f)=f \circ T$.  It would be appreciated if someone showed me a paper or other reference with a method for computing an orthonormal basis for $L^2(S^2)$ given some $U_T$.  For simplicity we can just use the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: As always, Fourier series of two variables are your friend.

Comment: $S^2$ is the sphere and not the torus, I am not sure about Fourier series.

Comment: Does $T$ preserve Lesbegues measure or is your question for any measure ?

Comment: @EtienneBfx i'll be fine with just lebeque since almost all the interesting stuff is absolutely continuous with respect to it.